Native build issue with Java java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject
Im trying to build my quarkus application in native mode using a dependency called EsperTech, and there is a specific snippet of code that after countless hours of debugging I discover that is causing issues for me. Basically it deals with some bytes being written to a buffer and read just after it (where it causes the following error).
java.io.InvalidClassException: my.package.CustomConfigurationClass; no valid constructor

The snippet of code is this one (I adapted to code to kotlin):
import com.espertech.esper.common.internal.util.SimpleByteArrayOutputStream
import com.espertech.esper.common.internal.util.ObjectInputStreamWithTCCL
import my.package.CustomConfigurationClass
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.ObjectInputStream
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream

fun <T> copy(configObj: T): T {
    val fbos = SimpleByteArrayOutputStream()
    val outStream = ObjectOutputStream(fbos)
    try {
        outStream.writeObject(orig)
        outStream.flush()
    } finally {
        outStream.close()
    }
    // ...

    val inStream: ObjectInputStream = ObjectInputStreamWithTCCL(fbos.inputStream)
    inStream.readObject() // Where the error happens
}

As you can see it throws exactly in the readObject function, I already checked, and yes, the buffer was properly saved before trying to read from it.
As the error suggests I try to make my class ready for native mode like this (worked for serialization when doing request/response apis, but not for this case, when working with java.io library).
@RegisterForReflection
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class CustomConfigurationClass(
    val name: String = "CustomConfigurationClass",
) : Serializable {
    constructor() : this("CustomConfigurationClass") // I know I do not need this but I try it to ensure either way
}

Is there any other way to handle this kind of serialization issues with the java.io std library?
I am assuming that this is the issue btw, but it can also be something else.
I tried to exclude this piece of code together with the java.io library from the native build using:
gradle build -x test -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.additional-build-args="--initialize-at-run-time=java.io\\,<esper_package>\\,etc"

But also no luck.

Solved!
I used the same solution posted here: Quarkus hibernate Exception in native mode
My serialization-config.json file:
[
  {"name":"java.io.ObjectInputStream"},
  {"name":"java.io.ObjectOutputStream"},
  {"name":"java.lang.String"},
  {"name":"my.custom.package.config.ConfigurationCustom"},
  ... Other esper library package
]

Every time I re-executed the native build I got this error messages:
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: SerializationConstructorAccessor class not found for declaringClass: com.espertech.esper.common.client.configuration.compiler.ConfigurationCompilerLanguage (targetConstructorClass: java.lang.Object). Usually adding com.espertech.esper.common.client.configuration.compiler.ConfigurationCompilerLanguage to serialization-config.json fixes the problem.

And just by following the suggestions (adding more packages to the serialization-config.json) I was able to execute successfully.
The only downside is to build every single time just to spot one more class/package to add in my json file, but this is how I manage to solve for now.
